# (Doom) Emacs Doesn't Replace Colon When I Type Over It, Gives Only Single " In F Strings

Tags: python, emacs, formatting

Running into this issue with Python at least, it likely appears elsewhere tho I don't know any other language enough to really figure it out for certain.
When I'm typing things out, like defining a function, it will give me the other side to most things that appear in pairs. (), {}, [], "", '', etc. But when I start an f string it doesn't give me the other half.
`print(f")` is what I get, which I've typed all of except the second parentheses. `print(f"")` is what's expected. When I go to close the quotes I wind up with an extra one which is a bit obnoxious, but not unbearable. `print(f"A {string} for example"")`

The other issue is that I wind up with two colons if it automatically places one for me. It won't let me overwrite it, despite it letting me do so with all other forms of punctuation.
`def function(a, b)::` is what I wind up with.
So I need to use arrow keys, hit escape and navigate with hjkl, or preemptively hit delete whenever I come up to a colon.

If you want to look through the Doom Emacs dotfiles I have then you can find them here: [Doom Emacs config](https://github.com/CopaDot/dotfiles/tree/master/.doom.d)